# CAT vs CATS in data step do loop

Tags: sas, do-loops

Why does the code below work (`&ds` is `12345678910`), but when I change `cats` to `cat`, `&ds` is just blank? I would expect changing `cats` to `cat` would mean `&ds` is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

```
data new;
  length ds $500;
  ds = "";
  do i = 1 to 10;
    ds = cats(ds, i, " ");
  end;
  call symputx('ds', ds);
run;
%put &ds;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the log?  There should be a message indicating why this isn't working.

Comment: I think you phrased your question backwards, "when I change cat to cats, &ds is just blank" when the opposite is true. It works for CATS but not CAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `cat()` will not trim the values so if you concatenate anything to `DS` and try to store it back into `DS` whatever you added is not stored because there is no room for it.

It appears you actually want the `catx()` function.

```
ds = catx(' ',ds, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS tends to add leading and trailing spaces if you use the input buffer and doing text manipulation. you can use either the Strip() and catx() functions to remove leading and trailing spaces. With catx() you have the extra option of specifying a delimiter.

```
ds = cat(strip(ds), i, " ");
```